# How do I create a list of dynamic Key/Value pairs in valid JSON in Ansible custom facts?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I'm trying to create a valid JSON list of key/values using "set_fact" in my ansible playbook.

Essentially I want my custom fact to look like this:

```
{
"containerports": [
    "10502" : "two",
    "11502" : "two",
    "10503" : "five", 
    "11503" : "five", 
], 
"numconnections": "2"
}
```

I can't figure out
1. How to Create dynamic variable names (the port numbers in this example) and 2. How to add this variable to my list "connectorports"

Currently I have this in my fact file:

```
{
"containerports": [
    "10502 : two", 
    "11502 : two", 
    "10503 : five", 
    "11503 : five", 
], 
}
```

I can't figure out how to get a JSON key:value mapping so that I can perform a select on my file. Every time I add a new port I want to be able to append to the list. My test.yml file looks like this:

```
      - name: Adding container ports to facts
    tags:
      - setup
    set_fact:
        containerports: "{{ containerports | default([]) }} + [ '{{ container_port }} {{ ':' }} {{ container_name }}' ]"
        cacheable: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost :)

```
containerports: "{{ containerports | default([]) }} + [ { container_port: container_name } ]"
```

In the same way that the '[]' are expanded into a list, so also is the '{}' inside expanded into a dictionary.

Comment: thank you! spent a while trying to figure out the syntax, also thank you for the additional explanation :)